# What are the arguments FOR Climate Change influenced by the drifting of Geomagnetic Poles?

Tags: climate-change, geomagnetism

***Over some years I was hovering over the developments of the ESA SWARM mission and probing random magnetometers from the Russian-Ukrainian observatories as a private researcher and a non-scientist.
I'm trained in social sciences, so I have no background or methodology in science as a discrete discipline
Did anyone else make a connection between drifting magnetic Poles, climate change, tropical relocations and such? Did anyone explore the Sun-Earth connectivity in relation to such changes? I leave some figments of research behind. I would be more than happy if I would be provided with an informed answer, thank you ***

Impact of the Geomagnetic Field and Solar Radiation on Climate Change

V. A. Dergacheva, S. S. Vasilieva, O. M. Raspopovb, and H. Jungnerc
a Ioffe Physical–Technical Institute, Russian Academy of Sciences, St. Petersburg

Pushkov Institute of Terrestrial Magnetism, Ionosphere, and Radiowave Propagation, Russian Academy of Sciences, St. Petersburg
cUniversity of Helsinki, Finland

> Abstract—Recent studies have shown that, in addition to the role of
>   solar variability, past climate changes may have been connected with
>   variations in the Earth’s magnetic field elements at various
>   timescales. An analysis of variations in geomagnetic field elements,
>   such as field intensity, reversals, and excursions, allowed us to
>   establish a link between climate changes at various timescales over
>   the last millennia. Of particular interest are sharp changes in the
>   geomagnetic field intensity and short reversals of the magnetic poles
>   (excursions). The beginning and termination of the examined
>   geomagnetic excursions can be attributed to periods of climate change.
>   In this study, we analyzed the possible link between short-term
>   geomagnetic variability (jerks) and climate change, as well as the
>   accelerated drift of the north magnetic pole and surface temperature
>   variations. The results do not rule out the possibility that
>   geomagnetic field variations which modulate the cosmic ray flux could
>   have played a major role in climate change in addition to previously
>   induced by solar radiation.

Gyre-driven decay of the Earth’s magnetic dipole

Christopher C. Finlay1, Julien Aubert2 & Nicolas Gillet3

> Direct observations indicate that the magnitude of the Earth’s
>   magnetic axial dipole has decreased over the past 175 years; it is now
>   9% weaker than it was in 1840. Here we show how the rate of dipole
>   decay may be controlled by a planetary-scale gyre in the liquid metal
>   outer core. The gyre’s meridional limbs on average transport normal
>   polarity magnetic flux equatorward and reverse polarity flux poleward.
>   Asymmetry in the geomagnetic field, due to the South Atlantic Anomaly,
>   is essential to the proposed mechanism. We find that meridional flux
>   advection accounts for the majority of the dipole decay since 1840,
>   especially during times of rapid decline, with magnetic diffusion
>   making an almost steady contribution generally of smaller magnitude.
>   Based on the morphology of the present field, and the persistent
>   nature of the gyre, the current episode of dipole decay looks set to
>   continue, at least for the next few decades
>
> Mid-Pliocene shifts in ocean overturning circulation and the onset of
>   Quaternary-style climates

[image]

M. Sarnthein1,2,*, G. Bartoli1,3, M. Prange4, A. Schmittner5, B. Schneider1, M. Weinelt1, N. Andersen6, and
D. Garbe-Schonberg

> The precession peaks found in the 3180 record from core MD900963 are
>   in excellent agreement with climatic oscillations predicted by the
>   astronomical theory of climate. Our ~180 record therefore permits the
>   development of an accurate astronomical time-scale. Based on our age
>   model, the BrunhesMatuyama reversal is dated at 775 + 10 ka, in good
>   agreement with the age estimate of 780 ka obtained by Shackleton et
>   al. [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCgui.jpg) and recent radiochronological A r / A r datings on lavas
>   [9-11].

The astronomical theory of climate and the age of the Brunhes-Matuyama magnetic reversal

Franck C. Bassinot, Laurent D. Labeyrie b, Edith Vincent a, Xavier Quidelleur, Nicholas J. Shackleton d, Yves Lancelot a

Comment: Quite well formulated question though. Might actually not be duplicate as OP specifically asked what are the arguments for this connection unlike in the existing 'is there a connection' question. Might be that there are arguments, but they are unproven.

Comment: @Communisty The original covers both "for" and "against" -- indeed, every answer to that question includes a "for" element. As to the formulation, I prefer the concise original. Three of the four papers quoted in the new question have nothing to do with geomagnetism-climate relationships, so they just distract from the question.

Comment: I can't see that you would've listed any arguments supporting a connection in your original answer.

Comment: @Communisty Please see final paragraph of my answer (“Of course, it's likely that geomagnetic field strength has *some* influence… sure enough, it turns out that Vieira and da Silva (2006) have found such an effect.”).